# How do i identify Name,place,objects,events from a text to generate RDF data?

Tags: rdf

Input will be the article and output should be the rdf data for it in FOAF (If any other ..pls Suggest) .My doubts are :

1) How do i train the system to identify the people,places,etc and generate the rdf structure ? 
2) After identification should i store it in database,then retrieve and generate the rdf structure?Is there any other way?

3) How can i use and apply OWL? (Web ontology language) 
Pls guide me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Named-entity recognition (NER) - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition (recognizing people and companies is what people often do, so you should be ok and find plenty of examples around). OpenNLP, LingPipe and GATE are just a few of the tools available to do NER and much more.
2. If you want to use OWL to do some inference over your RDF data, I suggest you store your RDF in a triple store (there are plenty freely available and open source triple stores).
3. This depends on the triple store you choose, some offers you OWL inference or you could use an inference engine as you add data to your store and use a triple store with no inference (i.e. total materialization). But, again, this might or might not be possible, depending on the amount of inference you actually need.